# Rails: undefined method map, Using map inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a collection of items for `options_for_select` using map inside my model:

```
  def get_products
    Product.all.map { |product| [product.description,product.id] }
  end
```

However rails is giving the error:

> undefined method `map' for :get_products:Symbol

Is not possible to use map inside models?

The code in the `view` is:

```
<%= f.select_tag :product_id, options_for_select(:get_products) %>
```

**Update**

Changing the code in the view to `get_products` instead of `:get_products` gives the error:

> undefined local variable or method `get_products' for #<#:0xb189c770>

Comment: May we see the line where you are calling `options_for_select`?

Comment: All of the above works fine (returns an array of arrays); chances are it's how you reference it in the `options_for_select` that's causing the problem -- perhaps it should be `get_products` instead of `:get_products`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options_for_select` expects a collection to be passed in and not a symbol. I'm fairly certain your error is coming from inside the Rails code and not your model.

Change `#get_products` to be a class method:

```
def self.get_products
  Product.all.map { |product| [product.description,product.id] }
end
```

And then in the view (assuming `#get_products` lives within a model called `Product`):

```
<%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(Product.get_products) %>
```

Comment: thank you very much, but shame on me there is no method `select_tag` for `form_for`. What should i do?

Comment: @EH_warch I updated my answer. I don't think you need `_tag` just `f.select`

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

`<%= f.select_tag :product_id, options_for_select(Product.get_products) %>`

Comment: Without adding the `self` to the method inside the model did not work

Comment: Yeah sorry thought you already had that, but I guess it was from @patricmcgraw's response